# Electron app in linux does not run node server react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, linux, electron

In my demoApp I want to start `node server/server.js` automatically when electron app is launched. The below code works perfectly for windows whereas for linux it starts the node server But I think there might be some issue with permission my application does not work as per the required

demoApp/public/electron.js

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow, protocol } = require("electron");
const url = require("url");
const { app, BrowserWindow, protocol } = require("electron");
const path = require("path");
const child_process = require("child_process");
let serverProcess;

//Create the main window.
function createWindow() {
    const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        //Set the path of an additional "preload" script
        webPreferences: {
            preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js"),
        },
    });
    if ((process.platform === "win32") || (process.platform === "win64")) {
        // For Windows, use spawn
        serverProcess = child_process.spawn("node", [path.join(__dirname, "../server/server.js")]);
    } else {
        // For macOS and Linux, use fork
        serverProcess = child_process.fork(path.join(__dirname, "../server/server.js"));
    }

 
    mainWindow.loadURL(!app.isPackaged ? 'http://localhost:3000' : `file://${__dirname}/../build/index.html`);

    // Open Chrome's DevTools in dev env.
    if (!app.isPackaged) {
        mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
    }
}

//Setup a local proxy to adjust the paths of requested files when loading
//them from the local production bundle (local fonts, etc)
function setupLocalFilesNormalizerProxy() {
    protocol.registerHttpProtocol(
        "file",
        (request, callback) => {
            const url = request.url.substr(8);
            callback({ path: path.normalize(`${__dirname}/${url}`) });
        },
        (error) => {
            if (error) console.error("Failed to register protocol");
        }
    );
}

//Finished initialization event to create the windows
app.whenReady().then(() => {
    createWindow();
    setupLocalFilesNormalizerProxy();

    app.on("activate", function () {
        //On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open
        if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
            createWindow();
        }
    });
});

//Quit when all windows are closed, except on macOS.
app.on("window-all-closed", function () {
    if (process.platform !== "darwin") {
        app.quit();
    }
    serverProcess.kill();

});
```

demoApp/server/server.js

```
app.post('/execute-jar', async (req, res) => {
    const file = req.files.file;
    const platform = os.platform();
    const downloadsFolderName = "Downloads";

    const downloadsFolderPath = path.join(os.homedir(), downloadsFolderName);
    // const fileNameNoSpaces = file.name.replace(/ /g, '_');
    const fileNameNoSpaces = file.name.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9._-]/g, '_');

    const parts = fileNameNoSpaces.split('.');
    const name = parts[0];
    const extension = parts[1];
    const filename = `${name}_temp.${extension}`;
    // Construct the full path to the file
    const filePath = path.join(downloadsFolderPath, filename);
    if (!file) {
        return res.status(400).json({ error: 'No file provided' });
    }

    try {
        await file.mv(filePath);
        const jarFilePath = path.join(__dirname, 'jar', 'test.jar');
        const outputFilePath = path.join(__dirname, 'test12.json');
        let cmd = `java -jar ${jarFilePath} ${outputFilePath} ${filePath}`;

        // Use sudo for macOS and Linux
        if ((platform !== 'win32') && (platform !== 'win64')) {
            cmd = `sudo ${cmd}`;
        }
        console.log(cmd);
        console.log('filePath', filePath)
        await execCommand(cmd);
        const schemaLog = path.join(__dirname, '../test32.log')
        const schemaFileContent = fs.readFileSync(schemaLog, 'utf-8');
        errorMessages = schemaFileContent.split('\n').filter(msg => msg.includes('ERROR')).slice(-2).join('\n');
        console.log('errorMessages', errorMessages)
        if (!fs.existsSync(outputFilePath)) {
            console.error('Error: Output file not generated');
            return res.status(500).json({ error: errorMessages });
        }

        const outputFileContent = fs.readFileSync(outputFilePath, 'utf-8');
        res.attachment('output.json');
        res.send(outputFileContent);
    } catch (executionError) {
        console.error('Error executing JAR file:', executionError.message);
    } finally {
        try {
            fs.unlinkSync(filePath);
            fs.unlinkSync(path.join(__dirname, 'output.json'));
        } catch (cleanupError) {
            console.error('Error cleaning up:', cleanupError.message);

        }
    }
});

function execCommand(cmd) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        exec(cmd, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
            if (error) {
                reject(error);
            } else {
                resolve();
            }
        });
    });
}
```